# How to reuse the "public" folder in a monorepo with multiple CRAs?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I use create-react-app in multiple packages in a monorepo. There is a fair amount of duplicated code and files in the "public" folder of each app, since they all have the same icons, descriptions, fonts etc.

Is there a way to move some or all of the files in the "public" folder to their own package, run them through a tool like [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and finally bundle them with create-react-app, without ejecting?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any open-source tool for this, so I wrote my own scripts:

**prepare_cra_files.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for app in apps/*/ ; do
  # Flush the files if they already exist
  if [ -d "$app"public ]; then
    rm -r "$app"public
  fi

  # Copy over the template files
  cp -r template "$app/public"
done

node templatify.js
```

**templatify.js**

```js
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");

const APPS_PATH = path.join(__dirname, "..", "apps");
const INDEX_HTML_TEMPLATE_PATH = path.join(__dirname, "template", "index.handlebars");

(async () => {
  const dirs = await fs.readdir(APPS_PATH);
  const indexHtmlTemplate = Handlebars.compile(await fs.readFile(INDEX_HTML_TEMPLATE_PATH, "utf-8"));

  dirs.forEach(async appName => {
    const indexHtmlContextPath = path.join(APPS_PATH, appName, "/handlebars/index.json");
    if (!fs.existsSync(indexHtmlContextPath)) {
      throw new Error(`Please provide the index.html context for the ${appName} appName`);
    }

    const indexHtmlContext = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(indexHtmlContextPath, "utf-8"));
    const indexHtml = indexHtmlTemplate(indexHtmlContext);

    await fs.writeFile(path.join(APPS_PATH, appName, "public", "index.html"), indexHtml);
    await fs.remove(path.join(APPS_PATH, appName, "public", "index.handlebars"));
  });
})();
```